landscape-sysinfo Missing Network Interface
I have a Dell server that I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS. It has two physical Ethernet interfaces, identified as eth0 and eth1. The landscape-sysinfo command used to display the IPv4 addresses for both interfaces, but I just noticed that the output now includes only the IPv4 address for eth0. The ifconfig command continues to display information for both interfaces. Why might this be?

I created a bug report for the issue. No one has responded to it yet. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/landscape-client/+bug/2081734
